# Can I make jQuery .load work for something more than a simple load to the HTML of an element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that does more than I have seen [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) used for:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            type: 'GET'
        })
        .success(function (content) {
            $('#content')
                .html("<div class='block-border'>" + content + "</div>")
                .applyTemplateSetup()
                .buildTableOfContent();
            if ($('#cityLegend-1').length) {
                $('#cityLegend-1').html("Question " + html);
            }
            $('#article').css('visibility', 'visible');
            var editHref = "/Admin/Contents/Edit?pk=0003000&rk=" + href.substring(2,5);
            $('#editContent').attr('data-href', editHref);
        })
        .fail(function (ajaxContext) {
            ajaxOnFailure(ajaxContext)
        });
```

Please note my content may contain HTML that's written by trusted sources internal to the group.

Can someone tell me if I can use jQuery load for this. I am thinking it's probably too much but I would just like to confirm this.

Also if I was able to use jQuery load then are there any advantages in using it. Sorry if this question does not sound so sensible but the reason I am asking all of this is that I would like to make use of a template function that I have been given that adds functionality to jQuery .load.

Comment: No you are not allowed to use `.load()` for this. I have reported you to the internet police.  :)

Comment: In this case, it seems `.load` would only save you a single line of code. I'd keep your current code. `.load` is just a shortcut anyway...

Comment: something unrelated... if you're concerned about performance. It'd probably be better to perform your templating functions (`applyTemplateSetup`, `buildTableOfContent`) on a `document fragment`that isn't attached to your dom. Attach it later when everything is ready :) [Access to DOM and manipulating it is a often bottleneck]

Comment: @Roman - Thanks for your comment about performance. Can you explain a bit more about what you mean "document fragment that isn't attached to your dom".

Comment: @Angela I can, but not in a comment (not enough space). Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*disclaimer: This isn't an answer to the original question, but it answers another one from the comments. (please forgive me, community).*

---

> If you're concerned about performance. It'd probably be better to
>   perform your templating functions (applyTemplateSetup,
>   buildTableOfContent) on a document fragmentthat isn't attached to your
>   dom. Attach it later when everything is ready :) [Access to DOM and
>   manipulating it is a often bottleneck]

---

> Can you explain a bit more about what you mean "document fragment that
>   isn't attached to your dom?

---

It's about minimizing "reflow".
Each time you access the DOM to manipulate it, the browser has to recalculate the size and position of pretty much everything (excluding browser specific optimizations).

So, it's better to manipulate the elements you receive per Ajax before you attach them to your document, this way the browser doesn't calculate anything. That is, calculate only once: when you attach the document fragment to the document. A document fragment is *"a lightweight container that can hold DOM nodes."*

in practice this means for you:

```
$.ajax({
    url: href,
    type: 'GET'
}).success(function (content) {
    var container = $('<div id="content">'); // create a new container
    //this new container is not attached to the document

    //the following manipulations cause no reflow
    container.html("<div class='block-border'>" + content + "</div>")
        .applyTemplateSetup()
        .buildTableOfContent();

    //attach the new container to the dom (replacing the old one)
    //reflowing the document only once
    $('#content').replaceWith(container);

    if ($('#cityLegend-1').length) {
        $('#cityLegend-1').html("Question " + html);
    }
    $('#article').css('visibility', 'visible');
    var editHref = "/Admin/Contents/Edit?pk=0003000&rk=" + href.substring(2, 5);
    $('#editContent').attr('data-href', editHref);
}).fail(function (ajaxContext) {
    ajaxOnFailure(ajaxContext)
});
```

based upon your html structure there are of course infinite ways of doing this. This is just one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main difference between using this and what you would typicall do with `load` would be that this is extensively manipulating the content returned via AJAX, calling other methods, etc.  You could certainly use `load` to do this by using a custom callback to do basically everything that this function is doing.

I guess I don't see what advantage you gain by doing this though.  Because really the main advantage of using `load` over `ajax`, `get`, etc. is that you could get a specific element out of the returned content and place it in the target node.  In this case, it seems all of the returned content is being used, so there is really no advantage gained in using `load`.

Comment: my reasons on this are that I would like to use a function that is available in my template skin that's a wrapper for jQuery load() method:  $(selector).loadWithEffect(url, data, callback);   Hopefully I can make the skin, wrapper and .load all work together nicely. Thanks for your help.